# MySQL select and lock in order to update with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have a PHP script which selects a code from an InnoDB table and dishes it out to a user. Once it's selected it, it goes back and updates the table.

Partial code:

`$read = "SELECT code FROM codes WHERE someCondition = true"`

Then:

`$update = "UPDATE codes SET status = 'assigned', timeAssigned = NOW() WHERE someCondition = true"`

How do I go about using InnoDB's locking to do this a bit more robustly and prevent two users getting the same codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relevant docs: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

```
SELECT FOR UPDATE code FROM codes ...
```

Comment: How do I amend the UPDATE query so it knows it's allowed to update the locked row?

Comment: You don't need to, as long its executed in the same connection. You also should have a transaction running.

Comment: @bcmcfc: the lock is established at the connection level. as long as you do the update using the same connection, it'll be allowed. If you try from some OTHER connection, then it's viewed as "someone else" trying to update the locked field.