# Update row before being read by another concomitant request MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a PHP page that gives each request a response which is a value from a table called TOKENS, each token retrieved must not be given to another requests, so I'm updating a field called "used" to 1 so the row can't be retrieved again, by using "WHERE used=0" condition.

```
<?php
// read an un used token
$sql = "SELECT tokenvalue FROM TOKENS WHERE used=0 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // set row status to used so it can't be retrieved again
        $sql = "UPDATE TOKENS SET used=1;";
        $conn->query($sql);

        echo ($row["tokenvalue"]);
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I tested the script by sending 50 requests at one time, many responses returned the same token as other responses it means they got interlaced, some requests has retrieved rows before being updated by the first requests obtaining the same row. here's the output of some of the requsts, hashes in bold are repeated.

**79835adf60b70abd4046b4ca3d3db74c**
**2f44bfa1cd1d66e4da39b7242e88ede1 2f44bfa1cd1d66e4da39b7242e88ede1 2f44bfa1cd1d66e4da39b7242e88ede1** 4320f3a5273b493258ba66db4028fcc2      **79835adf60b70abd4046b4ca3d3db74c** 9d3cb74140368befbe6fd9dc0ca209a1    **47a8e01fec82a44af3b1bd63f3e77816 47a8e01fec82a44af3b1bd63f3e77816 47a8e01fec82a44af3b1bd63f3e77816** 2a9ae219d2d57f9988caff3baf48b9b3

I have searched here on stackoverflow but I found no similar question.
How can I make a row read only once by a request?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929881/mysql-select-and-lock-in-order-to-update-with-php?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL select and lock in order to update with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929881/mysql-select-and-lock-in-order-to-update-with-php)

Comment: I tried the FOR UPDATE syntax but I still getting duplicate values. "SELECT tokenvalue FROM TOKENS WHERE used=0 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solutions, thanks for the guys who commented, using FOR UPDATE alone in the select request was was not enough, the SELECT and UPDATE have to be wrapped in a transaction, like this:

```
 <?php
    // Begin transaction
    $conn->begin_transaction();
    $sql = "SELECT tokenvalue FROM TOKENS WHERE used=0 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // set row status to used so it can't be retrieved again
            $sql = "UPDATE TOKENS SET used=1;";
            $conn->query($sql);
    
            echo ($row["tokenvalue"]);
            break;
        }
    }
    // finish transaction
    $conn->commit();
?>
```